# Read directly from hard drive sector without any third party in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read directly from hard drive sector in java but I can't find relevant classes about it all I found is java random access file direct allocate method which reads from buffer but not from a hard drive sector is there a way to read directly at sector level?

Comment: There is no native SDK support for this, as it's highly specific to a particular environment. However, if the particular OS exposes access via IO like "/dev/sd*".. which in turn may allow 'direct' access.. YMMV.

Comment: You should use JNI, write a native method in C

Comment: Is there any way in c# without need to write native method?